# In django oracle backend, is it possible to configure/replace convert_unicode function?

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-orm, cx-oracle

In https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py you can find this fragment of code:

```
if int(Database.version.split('.', 1)[0]) >= 5 and \
        (int(Database.version.split('.', 2)[1]) >= 1 or
         not hasattr(Database, 'UNICODE')):
    convert_unicode = force_text
else:
    convert_unicode = force_bytes
```

`convert_unicode` is global variable.

In my appliacation I need to change it to something else (PLEASE DON'T ASK ME WHY, JUST TRUST THAT I NEED TO). What is a simples way to do this?

One option is to define my own backend, which would inherit from oracle backend and overwrite functions like this one:

```
def savepoint_create_sql(self, sid):
        return convert_unicode("SAVEPOINT " + self.quote_name(sid))
```

To this:

```
def savepoint_create_sql(self, sid):
        return MY_convert_unicode("SAVEPOINT " + self.quote_name(sid))
```

But I believe there is a simpler solution I'm just not aware of...

Comment: I suppose this question in no longer valid, as oracle's backend was rewritten...